# Open JPEG2000 (Sentinel 2) in R

Tags: raster, r, jpeg-2000

Is there any way I can open Sentinel 2 JPEG2000 file (`.jp2`) using R? Or more specifically with the `{raster}` package in R? 
I keep getting the Error message that `.jp2` is:

> not recognised as a supported file format.

Do you know if this file format will be added to the raster package any time soon, or how to open it in R without converting it to `.tif` first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [`rgdal`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) package and ensure that your version of GDAL has the JPEG2000 Driver. For instance:

```
library(rgdal)
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.1-10, (SVN revision 622)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/1.11
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012, [PJ_VERSION: 480]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
Linking to sp version: 1.2-3
```

Then read in the jp2 file:

```
> s2a <- readGDAL('S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_SGS__20151221T173303_A002594_T29UMT_B12.jp2')

S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_SGS__20151221T173303_A002594_T29UMT_B12.jp2 has GDAL driver JPEG2000 
and has 5490 rows and 5490 columns
```

Check the output:

> summary(s2a)

```
Object of class SpatialGridDataFrame
Coordinates:
  min     max
x  399960  509760

y 5690220 5800020

Is projected: TRUE 

proj4string :

[+proj=utm +zone=29 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]

Grid attributes: 
  cellcentre.offset cellsize cells.dim
x            399970       20      5490
y           5690230       20      5490

Data attributes:
 band1      
 Min.   :    0  
 1st Qu.:  198  
 Median :  606  
 Mean   : 1080  
 3rd Qu.: 1430  
 Max.   :28000
```

Comment: I have rgdal 1.1-10 and GDAL 2.0.1. However I still get the same error message with readGDAL(): `not recognised as a supported file format`

Comment: Is JPEG-2000 listed when you run `gdalDrivers()`, e.g.`66         JPEG2000                       JPEG-2000 part 1 (ISO/IEC 15444-1)`

Comment: No! Do I have to reinstall GDAL/rgdal?

Comment: Probably. You should check if JPEG2000 is listed when you run `gdalinfo --formats`

Comment: I reinstalled GDAL and rgdal: From my cmd line `gdalinfo --formats` returns JP2000, however `gdalDrivers()` doesn't. Any clue?

Comment: I have the same problem. I did manage to run some operations with `library(gdalUtils)
gdal_chooseInstallation('JP2OpenJPEG')`but working directly through gdal would be better. see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044403/gdal-jp2-driver-missing-in-python

Comment: could someone provide more details?  gdalDrivers() doesn't include JP2000 using `rgdal` package.  What is the command to import raster files using the `gdalUtils` package?

Answer (score 2):

The provided solutions seem to work just fine. But I prefere working with the `{raster}` package, so I wrote a little function:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(raster)
    library(rgdal)


    jp2_to_raster <- function(jp2_path, ref_crs) {
      # read ".jp2" and convert to raster
      sen2_GDAL <- readGDAL(jp2_path)
      sen2_GDAL %>% 
        as.matrix() %>% 
        t() %>% 
        raster(crs=ref_crs, 
               xmn=xmin(sen2_GDAL), xmx=xmax(sen2_GDAL), 
               ymn=ymin(sen2_GDAL), ymx=ymax(sen2_GDAL)) -> tmp_raster

      # get band number from file path
      strsplit(jp2_path, "_")[[1]][length(strsplit(jp2_path, "_")[[1]])] %>% 
        strsplit(".jp2") %>% 
        as.character() -> names(tmp_raster)

      return(tmp_raster)
    }

    file <- "T10UDV_20190630T190919_B01"
    crs <- "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

    raster <- jp2_to_raster(file , crs(crs))
```

Or use lapply to convert the whole Sentinel2 scene to a `raster::stack`:

```
    SEN2_PATHS <- list.files(pattern = "*.jp2$", full.names = T)
    raster _stack <- raster::stack(lapply(SEN2_PATHS, jp2_to_raster, ref_crs = crs(crs)))
```

Comment: This is a bit unnecessary as `readGDAL` results in a SpatialPixelsDataFrame and there is a coercion method for raster or stack. You can simply do something like: `raster(readGDAL("C:/myraster.jpg"))` and skip the matrix coersion and transposition.

Comment: Great this works perfectly. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: This was helpful. The strsplit band number names did not work for me. I modified to: names(tmp_raster) <- as.character(regmatches(jp2_path,gregexpr("B0\\d", jp2_path)))

Answer (score 0):

You say "without converting to tif first", but it appears that many are struggling to make `rgdal` to understand that the OpenJPEG driver is actually included in the GDAL distribution. If you cannot manage to make the driver work in rgdal, you can translate the `.jp2` file to `GeoTIFF` and open that file with rgdal. Translating can be done using the command line as explained [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_sentinel2.html) or the `gdal_translate` wrapper from the gdalUtils package:

```
library(rgdal)
library(gdalUtils)

gdal_translate("T33XVJ_20170803T125711_B01.jp2", "B01.tif")
b01 <- readGDAL("B01.tif")
# B01.tiff has GDAL driver GTiff 
# and has 1830 rows and 1830 columns
```