# Import Sentinel2 (jpeg2000) in R

Tags: r, rgdal, sentinel-2, jpeg-2000

I'm trying to import a Sentienl 2 image into RStudio (Version 1.0.136) using rgdal (v. 1.2-5) package. However, it seems something is wrong. My OS is macOS Sierra v. 10.12.1

S2<- readGDAL("S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_SGS__20160916T153615_A006454_T34VCR_B12.jp2")
Error in .local(.Object, ...) :

I have checked gdalDrivers() and this is what I got:

64  JPEG JPEG JFIF  FALSE  TRUE     TRUE

I've checked already this link but didn't work for me
[Open JPEG2000 (Sentinel 2) in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211157/open-jpeg2000-sentinel-2-in-r/226074#226074)

I think I have to instal the jpeg2000 driver but not sure about how to do it.

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: There are at least four questions on gis stackexchange with this exact question but none of them provide a usable answer.