# Read JPEG2000 in R for subsequent random forest classification

Tags: raster, r, jpeg-2000

I want to use random forests in R to classify an image. My image is in jp2 format. I read [Open JPEG2000 (Sentinel 2) in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211157/open-jpeg2000-sentinel-2-in-r) and updated my rdal:

```
rgdal: version: 1.2-5, (SVN revision 648)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15
```

Still, I see only JPEG not JPER2000 when I run `gdalDrivers()`. Translation into tiff is not an option for me as my image is ~800 Gb if uncompressed (more than my c drive) and gdal is not implementing random forests.

I also tried
`gdal_chooseInstallation('JP2OpenJPEG')`
`library(rgdal)`
`myimage <- readGDAL('filename.jp2')`.

But even after exhaustive googling I can't figure out how `gdal_chooseInstallation('JP2OpenJPEG')` works. All I am getting is `Error in .local(.Object, ...) :`

How to I read jp2 image in R without translating it other formats so I can apply random forests?

Comment: I recommend you to use the `terra` package since `raster` will be deprecated soon

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but I have the same problem today. I tried to open a JPG2000 image (sentinel-2) without success. Since GDAL is supporting this driver a long time ago, was weird couldn't open it.

What I tried:

- Update `rgdal`
- Update `gdal` (I'm a Mac OS user, so I tried with `brew install gdal`, `pip install gdal`, [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/) installation files, etc)

All this with failure.

I surfed into rgdal installation folder seeing gdal binaries inside, so that was a surprise for me.

[image]

I deleted rgdal folder and reinstalled the library. Now opening S2 images works:

```
library(rgdal)
## Loading required package: sp
## rgdal: version: 1.4-4, (SVN revision 833)
## Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
## Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28
## Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2/share/gdal
## GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
## Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 6.1.1, July 1st, 2019, [PJ_VERSION: 611]
## Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
## Linking to sp version: 1.3-1 

library(raster)

raster("T19JBG_20190822T143759_B01.jp2")
 ## class       : RasterLayer 
 ## dimensions  : 1830, 1830, 3348900  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
 ## resolution  : 60, 60  (x, y)
 ## extent      : 199980, 309780, 6590200, 6700000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 ## coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
 ## data source : /Users/aldotapia/Downloads/test/T19JBG_20190822T143759_B01.jp2 
 ## names       : T19JBG_20190822T143759_B01 
 ## values      : 0, 65535  (min, max)
```

Paths of R libraries in Mac OS are in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/library` and `Path to GDAL shared files:` gave me the clue of my problem (loading `rgdal` library)

Comment: The current version of rgdal is 1.6-2, not a 1.4.-4: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html I suggest you upgrade the package with install.packages("rgdal").

Comment: Oh, yes. But the answer if from 2019, at that time 1.4-4 was the current version

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdalUtils to convert it to a different format and then read it. It may not keep the data in a jp2 format but, it does keep you in R.

```
library(raster)
library(gdalUtils)

gdalUtils::gdal_translate("band01.jp2", "band01.tif")
  b01 <- raster::raster("Band01.tif")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the easiest way using the terra package:

```
library(terra)

r <- rast("folder/file1.jp2")
```

The `r` variable will be a SpatRast object similar to the old RasterStack of the raster package. Please, see [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/index.html).