# How to open jp2 JPEG2000 files in R

Tags: gdal, r, jpeg-2000

I'm re-opening this question ([Open JPEG2000 (Sentinel 2) in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211157/open-jpeg2000-sentinel-2-in-r)). I'm working on a Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

I would like to be able to read jp2 format images with R without translating it to .tif format or anything of that kind.

I followed what have been explained in this question, but I'm still not able to open jp2 images.

```
library(rgdal)
Le chargement a nécessité le package : sp
rgdal: version: 1.2-7, (SVN revision 660)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded 
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24
Path to GDAL shared files: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgdal/gdal
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 491]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version: 1.2-4
```

Then :

```
s04 <- readGDAL("/Users/martinmonziols/Documents/ENSAE/Stage TheGreenData/L2A_T30UYA_20170509T105621_B04_10m.jp2")
Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
```

So, I checked the drivers

```
library(gdalUtils)
gdalDrivers()
```

It seems that I don't have any driver for jp2 files. But what is strange to me is that when running these lines in Terminal

```
MacBook-Air-de-Martin:~ martinmonziols$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
```

And

```
gdalinfo --formats
```

I have in particular this line in the table of all drivers:

```
JPEG2000 -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 part 1 (ISO/IEC 15444-1), based on Jasper library
```

which means that I have somewhere a driver for jp2 format. But R is not speaking to this one since the versions differ and this driver does not appear in the list I have in R.

What am I missing here ? how can I force R to use the right gdal version instead of the older one ?

Comment: I don't have a mac but I think `rgdal` comes with its own gdal binaries on that platform, and these binaries apparently don't include the jp2 driver. Try re-installing the package with `install.package('rgdal', type='source')` for `rgdal` to dynamically bind with your system gdal installation. You may have to adjust the `configure.args=` too. Also you can use `raster()` directly to read the band, without having to use `readGDAL()`.

Comment: Could you provide more details?  How is it possible to adjust with `configure.args=`? Using `raster`() returns the error message: `Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.`

Comment: @LoïcDutrieux Could you please elaborate on your comment-answer?

Comment: @user3386170 How did you install `rgdal`? Running `rgdal::gdalDrivers()$name` will give you the list of drivers available by your `rgdal` installation; it must include any of `JP2OpenJPEG` or `SENTINEL2` for you to be able to read sentinel 2 data directly into R. The only difference between `raster()` and `readGDAL()` is the class of object returned (`RasterLayer` vs `SpatialGridDataFrame`).They both use `rgdal` in the background and therefore require the mentioned drivers.

Comment: @LoïcDutrieux I initially installed `rgdal` via the typical user interface. I also tried using the code you suggested with `install.packages('rgdal', type='source')`. With both types of install, the list returned under `rgdal::gdalDrivers()$name` does not include `JP2OpenJPEG` nor `JPEG2000`, only  `SENTINEL2` and `JPEG`.  When I try `readGDAL('filename.jp2')`, it returns the following error message: `Error in .local(.Object, ...) :` .  You had proposed something to do with `configure.args=` but I don't know how to pursue that further.

Answer (score 5):

Martin, I had the same problem, very frustrating!

What worked for me was compiling my own version of the rgdal package using my local system's version of GDAL and PROJ4 as Loic Dutrieux's suggested. If you've installed GDAL using KyngChaos packages you should be able to do so by executing the following command in R:

```
install.packages("rgdal", type = "source", configure.args="--with-gdal-config=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/unix/bin/gdal-config --with-proj-include=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/include --with-proj-lib=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/lib --with-proj-share=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/share/proj --with-proj-data=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/share/proj --with-data-copy=yes")
```

If you do not yet have a separate install of GDAL on your system (check by running 'gdalinfo --version' in a MacOS terminal), you will have to download and install the 'GDAL Complete' framework from KyngChaos first: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks

I ran into trouble with various versions of GDAL on my system and was unable to compile the package, so I ended up starting with a clean install of R, GDAL and all associated packages. Then it worked. Hopefully, this won't be needed in your case!

--

UPDATE: *To ensure the home-build rgdal package works like the binaries on CRAN, the GDAL and PROJ4 data files need to be included. I have updated the line of code above with two additional arguments.*

Comment: Great workaround! I understand the headache of this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I realize that the original question was about Mac OS but could you provide some hints on how to adapt this solution to Windows.  I don't have GDAL installed (unless it is part of QGIS... or dnrgps?).

Comment: @user3386170 While it is theoretically possible to install rgdal from source on windows too, it is far from easy and for that reason usually not recommended. See this [r-sig-geo thread](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Trying-to-install-rgdal-from-source-on-Windows-7-and-failing-td7587144.html) about compiling rgdal

Comment: @LoïcDutrieux Essentially, you are saying that, for a beginner user on Windows, it is difficult to make R be able to read .jp2... ?  I can give up and just use QGIS to convert from .jp2 to .tiff (I just find it more elegant and more efficient to run all my code in R) if that is a more doable option.

Comment: @user3386170 That's right, on windows you're pretty much bound to using the gdal binaries that come statically linked to `rgdal` and they do not include all drivers (e.g.: jp2, hdf4). An alternative is to use `gdalUtils::gdal_translate()` to generate a tiff from the jp2 and `raster()` to read the geotTiff into R. This works because the `gdalUtils` calls the gdal that comes with QGIS (or another one, but QGIS is the most common option) via `system()`. This is of course a lot less efficient than reading the jp2 files directly, but afraid it's the only option on windows