# JPEG2000 on Mac in R

Tags: gdal, r, mac, jpeg-2000

I want to use JPEG2000 images in R on a Mac. The problem is if I use custom rgdal downloaded from CRAN, the function raster does not recognize JPEG2000 images. 
Therefore Jakob described a workaround (Link to the old question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260487/163399) which worked for me last year:

```
install.packages("rgdal", type = "source", configure.args="--with-gdal-config=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/unix/bin/gdal-config --with-proj-include=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/include --with-proj-lib=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/lib --with-proj-share=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/share/proj --with-proj-data=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/share/proj --with-data-copy=yes")
```

But when I try it nowadays on a new Mac with a new R-setup (RStudio: Version 1.2.5033, R: R 3.6.3) it does not work anymore. I installed GDAL using KyngChaos packages (GDAL 2.4.2) but when I execute the command Jakob mentioned, there are the following error messages:

```
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** Paket ‘rgdal’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** using staged installation
configure: R_HOME: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++ -std=gnu++11
configure: C++11 support available
configure: rgdal: 1.4-7
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 845
configure: gdal-config set to /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/unix/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config exists... yes
checking gdal-config executable... yes
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 2.4.2
checking C++11 support for GDAL >= 2.3.0... yes
checking GDAL version >= 1.11.4... yes
checking GDAL version <= 2.5 or >= 3.0... yes
checking gdal: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: gdal-config data directory readable... yes
checking GDAL: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Resources/gdal/pcs.csv readable... yes
./configure: line 2107: pkg-config: command not found
configure: pkg-config proj not available
set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory containing proj.pc
configure: PROJ version not determined using pkg-config proj
configure: proj CPP flags:  -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/include 
configure: PROJ LIBS: -L/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/lib 
checking PROJ header API:... proj_api.h
checking proj_api.h presence and usability... yes
checking PROJ version >= 4.8.0... yes
configure: PROJ_LIB: /Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/share/proj
./configure: line 2350: test: =: unary operator expected
checking PROJ: proj.db found and readable... no
Error: proj/proj.db not found
Either install missing proj support files, set PROJ_LIB to the correct path, and if need be use the --with-proj-share= configure argument.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

I controlled the corresponding files in the directories and everything seems to be correctly installed. Do you have an idea or solution?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please edit your question and explain what you're trying to do, what's expected, and include the actual code you're trying to use.

Comment: @Simbamangu Thanks, yes I tried to describe it as best and detailed as I could!